# Pivot Tables - using more than one column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

With Pivot Tables is it possible to base your columns on two values (in my example 'code' and 'val')?  By the looks of it you can't, but that seems a bit of a limitation to me, so perhaps I've just misunderstood something.  For example if my data table looks like this:

code val total
----    ---  -----
SI     12  90
SI     12  30
SI     24  240
CI     12  210

and the output I desire is this:

SI12 SI24 CI12
----    ----    ----
120   240   210

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me how this could be achieved whether the solution is to use Pivot Tables or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
  (
     code  VARCHAR(2),
     val   INT,
     total INT
  )

INSERT INTO @mytable
VALUES      ('SI',
             12,
             90),
            ('SI',
             12,
             30),
            ('SI',
             24,
             240),
            ('CI',
             12,
             210)

SELECT *
FROM   @mytable

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT code + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), VAL) VAL,
               total
        FROM   @mytable) T
       PIVOT(sum(total)
            FOR VAL IN ([SI12],
                        [SI24],
                        [CI12])) AS PIVOTTABLE
```